# Displaying values in ListBox based on Dropdoown values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax, html.listboxfor

In my view I have one dropdown Role and second ListBox as Permissions. I want to change the values in ListBox as User selects the values in Dropdown Role

```
<tr> 
<td>@Html.Label("","Role")</td>
<td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Role, @ViewBag.role as SelectList, new { @class = "dropdown"} )</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>@Html.Label("","Permissions in Role")</td>
<td>@Html.ListBox("permissions", @ViewBag.permissions as SelectList, new { @class = "chosen-select", data_placeholder = "Add Permissions to Role...", style = "width:500px;", tabindex = "4"})</td>
</tr>
```

In My js file  (Updated After Stephen Suggestion)

```
   $(document).on('change', '#Role_RefID', function () {
    var selection = $(this).val();
    $.getJSON(window.location.pathname + "/getPermissions?id="+selection, function (result) {
    var ddl = $('#permissions');
    ddl.empty().trigger("chosen:updated");
    $(result).each(function () {
            $(document.createElement('option'))
                .attr('value', this.Id)
                .text(this.Value)
                .appendTo(ddl)
                .attr('selected',"selected") 
            ;
        });
        ddl.trigger("chosen:updated");
    });
});
```

getPermissions (Updated after Stephen Suggestion)

```
  public JsonResult getPermissions(int id)
    {         
        List<Reference> perms = rep.permsInRole(id);
        var res = perms.Select(p => new { Id = p.RefID, Value = p.Description }).Distinct().ToList();          
        return Json(res, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

ListBox displays the initial values from DB but when I change the values in dropdown It doesnt clear the contents of Listbox and also doesnt display the new values in ListBoxListBox

Comment: Show your `getPermissions()` method - what does it return?

Comment: Thanks Stephen...getPermissions return a string and its returning values I verified it

Comment: You need to return Json containing the option value and display text and then use a loop to render the options in the ajax success function

Comment: I try that, but it should atleat clear the values first which it doesnt ....

Comment: It just needs to be `$('#permissions').empty();` although I'm guessing you might be using a plugin (chosen?) for the listbox as well - if so you would need to call its refresh/update method as well.